# How do I inject cookies when using a cookie jar in CURL?

Tags: php, curl

I am using php curl and i am using the cookie jar for a multi-step crawl. I need the dynamically generated cookies from the server.

But at one step some cookies are generated using javascript. Since curl doesn't run javascript I need to inject cookies to curl at this point.

The only way I can see doing this is manually reading the cookie file, and setting all the cookies plus the ones I want using `curl_Setopt` and `CURLOPT_COOKIE`.

Is there a way to inject cookies without loosing the ones already there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found if you use the cookie jar, and `curl_setopt` wit `CURLOPT_COOKIE` it doesn't overwrite the cookies it loaded from the file, it just appends them.

So the answer is to use `CURLOPT_COOKIE`.

Thanks Byron!