# Submiting an ajax form with php

Tags: php, ajax, forms, html-parsing

i'm building a php program to get 3 variables from a website and calculate them and then post the result, I can read the variables, calculate them, but the posting part is difficult to me because it uses an Ajax form ( I think ) is posting possible with php using XMLhttprequest?

this is the submit button:

```
<a href="#" class="formSubmit" tabindex="3">
```

this is the message box:

```
<textarea name="message" id="messageContent" rows="18" wrap="virtual" tabindex="2"></textarea>
```

I've tried to handle it like a regular form but it didn't work, I tracked down the ajax function to post:

```
function formSubmitFunction(e,action, target){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#messageContent").attr("value") == undefined || $("#messageContent").attr("value").length < 2){
        alert("A mensagem precisa ter no mÃ­nimo 2 caracteres.");
        $("#messageContent").focus();
        return false;
    }else {
        $("#formSubmit").html('<img src="http://website.com/'+desTheme+'/images/send_post.gif');
        if(action == "post"){
            $("#formAjax").append('<div id="carregando"></div>');
            PostFunctions.insertPost(topicId,$("#messageContent").val(), callbackInsertPost);
        } else {
            var postId = target.replace("#","");
            $("#formAjax").append('<div id="carregando"></div>');           
            PostFunctions.editPost(postId,$("#messageContent").val(), callbackEditPost);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

help

@edit:

found the other insertPost function

```
function callbackInsertPost(response){
        var result = eval("("+response+")");
        if($("#popup").length){
            $("#popup").remove();
        }
        if(!result.error){
            var returnMessage = "";
            if(result.isForumModerated){
                returnMessage = '<div id="popup" class="autoClear simple">'
                                    +'Sua mensagem estÃ¡ aguardando a aprovaÃ§Ã£o da moderaÃ§Ã£o.'
                                    +'</div>';
                $("#carregando").remove();
                $(actualPostId).prepend(returnMessage);
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#popup").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                        $("#popup").remove();
                    });
                },5000);
            $("#formAjax").remove();
            } else {
                //console.log(result);
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    document.location = "_t_lastpost_"+topicId+"_"+forumId+"?postId="+result.postId;
                },1500);
                /*returnMessage = '<div id="popup" class="autoClear simple">'
                                    +'Mensagem enviada com sucesso! Clique neste <a href="_t_lastpost_'+topicId+'_'+forumId+'">link</a> para ver sua mensagem'
                                    +'</div>';*/
            }
        } else {
            if(result.nickname_reproved){
                document.location = "changenickname.jbb";
            } else {
                $("#carregando").remove();
                for(i = 0; i < result.messages.length; i++){
                    $("#formAjax").prepend('<div id="popup" class="autoClear error-post">'
                                        +result.messages[i]+'<br/>'
                                        +'</div>'); 
                    }
                $.scrollTo("#popup",500);
                $("#formSubmit").html('<a href="#" class="formSubmit" tabindex="3"><img src="'+baseImages+'/themes/'+desTheme+'/images/pm_send.gif"/></a>');
                $(".formSubmit").bind("click",function(e){
                    formSubmitFunction(e,"post")
                });
            }
        }
}
```

@edit2:

```
PostFunctions.insertPost = function(p0, p1, callback) {
    DWREngine._execute(PostFunctions._path, 'PostFunctions', 'insertPost', p0, p1, callback);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using jquery but the actual `post` functions are located in the `PostFunctions` object. You need to show the code of that section and explain what the problem is exactly.

Comment: found it, edited on the main post, the problem is: I can't post a new message using curl since the submit button is using ajax, can I do that using PHP ?

Comment: @André Cardoso, you can absolutely post using cURL.  AJAX is nothing special... it is just normal HTTP like anything else.

Comment: No, you have just added the callback function that is called after a successful post.

Comment: this is the last function I could track on the source code, added on @edit2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget all the JavaScript stuff you are looking at. When emulating the browser, you just have to recreate the requests sent to the server.

1. Open up fiddler or firebug's net panel.
2. Do the post in your browser.
3. Look for the ajax post in fiddler/firebug.
4. Create a regular post using PHP curl using the same parameters you saw
   in fiddler.

Make sure you check the headers in case javascript set some cookies.

**EDIT**

- The cookie file It is created by curl and has a different format than fiddler. Delete it and let curl create it.
- Is `c0-id`  a hidden form field? View source. If it changes when you look at it in another browser, you need to scrape the form, then do the post you have written based on that value.

  - Post to the page that displays the form. Use `CURL_OPT_COOKIEJAR`.
  - `CURL_OPT_COOKIEJAR` it useful if you post to two different pages because it remembers cookies set from the last request, just like a browser.
- Make sure your user-agent is a real browser.
- Watch both the browser and your script hit the server through fiddler. You want your script to behave exactly as the browser does. So keep tweaking your script to make it closer. Eventually it will work.
- Scraping websites can be very frustrating and time consuming at first. Just keep at it.

  - Organize your code into functions and classes. It will be easier to do multiple posts this way.

Comment: found this:

callCount=1
c0-scriptName=PostFunctions
c0-methodName=insertPost
c0-id=6001_1310347486332
c0-param0=number:1576140
c0-param1=string:fiddler%20hehe%20haha%20searchme
xml=true

i will try that, but javascript did set some cookies, what should I do with them?

Comment: You will have to set them yourself. Look at curls cookie handling. And view this post i made here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622596/how-do-i-inject-cookies-when-using-a-cookie-jar-in-curl

Comment: Thanks, but one problem: I posted twice and the cookies set are different from eachother, what should I do ? find how they are generated in the source code ? can I find that ?

Comment: Look to see if you find a Set-Cookie: header when you execute a GET of  the form (before you post). The server could be setting cookies. Otherwise you need to grep the source for jquery cookie setting, or pure javascript (document.cookie) code. Then figure out what it is doing and reproduce in php.

Comment: oops, apparently I send this next answer with another account, because I were on another computer, can you read it ? thank you very much Byron